# Compare two dataframes based on conditions in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to compare records from one dataframe with another dataframe and find a match, stop the iteration for that record if a match is found based on a condition and return a result.

1st DataFrame

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | 23 |
| John | Doe | 24 |

2nd DataFrame

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Doe | 23 |
| John | Doe | 24 |

Conditions

| Array | Value |
| --- | --- |
| [1,1,1] | D |
| [0,1,1] | F |

In the output I want to compare values from first Dataframe with 2nd df and generate a binary based on comparison like [0,1,1] or [1,1,1] and check if this list is present in conditions df, if present return the value corresponding to it.

Output

| A | B | C | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | 23 | F |
| John | Doe | 24 | D |

Comment: Spark dataframes are unordered. "1st record" is undefined in Spark.

Comment: @mck what will be a better approach to achieve the output in optimized way. when I tried with joins it is multiplying the number of matching values ex, 2 values in first df * 2 values in 2nd df = 4 records, and these array values are checked against conditions and filtering it out to 2 records.

Comment: Your question is undefined. There is no answer.